# Get indexes of strings in List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the below code using LINQ?
Basically I'd like to get a List of all the indexes of where strings from one list are present in another list.

```
private List<int> GetColumnIndexesToIgnore(
     ReadOnlyCollection<string> listOfColumnsToIgnore, List<string> columnHeadings)
{
    List<int> columnIndexesToIgnore = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < columnHeadings.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listOfColumnsToIgnore.Contains(columnHeadings[i]))
        {
            columnIndexesToIgnore.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return columnIndexesToIgnore;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with LINQ like this:

```
var res = columnHeadings
    .Select((v, i) => new {Value = v, Index = i})
    .Where(p => listOfColumnsToIgnore.Contains(p.Value))
    .Select(p => p.Index)
    .ToList();
```

The first `Select` pairs up values and their indexes, `Where` clause filters out the pairs that you do not want, the second `Select` harvests the indexes back, and `ToList` makes the `List<int>` out of them.

Comment: In addition, it's also possible to drop the `ToList()` and change the method's return to `IEnumerable<int>` to get the benefit of lazy evaluation, if that's a fit for the OP's requirements.

Comment: Side note: if you have sizable amount of items converting `listOfColumnsToIgnore` to `HashSet<string>` first may be beneficial (try and measure).

Comment: @jdphenix The problem with returning `IEnumerable<int>` is a possibility to enumerate it multiple times without really noticing. I do use `IEnumerable`s inside a single method, but I turn results into lists before returning in most cases simply to avoid a possibility of multiple enumerations.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the indexes of the items that match and -1 for the others, then filter out the -1 values:

```
List<int> columnIndexesToIgnore = columnHeadings
  .Select((c, i) => listOfColumnsToIgnore.Contains(c) ? i : -1)
  .Where(i => i != -1)
  .ToList();
```